# Handling width 100% elements on mobile

Tags: html, css, class, select, bootstrap-4

I have a very basic question but I don't really find a clear answer. I use bootstrap for styling a website and am struggling to make it mobile-responsive.

I use the following code to display a button next to a select as suggested in this answer :

```
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control mb-3" aria-label="Default select example" id="selection-object" name="selection-object" onchange="changeText(this);">
                    <option value="select">Select an element</option>
                    {% for element in elements %}
                        <option value='{{ element .content }}'>{{ element |string }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <div class="input-group-addon input-group-button">
                    <button type="submit" id="modify_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Modify</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My main problem is that I also use :

```
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
```

to split my page in 2.

But my problem is that when I reduce the size of the screen, the columns are not responsive anymore, like this :

[image]

How can I do then to make those 2 columns responsive, the one on the right under the one on the left ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/columns/#how-they-work
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

You can read the documentation.
basicly bootstrap using div and classes like

1. container -> handle one section
2. row -> handle row of each section
3. col -> this col to handle responsive thing

so add div with class col-sm for small, col-md for medium to wrap your code inside it, so it allow responsive bootstrap class to do its job

Comment: Hi I'll see if it works better and come back to you then. Thank you !